# SecurityException while broadcasting protected intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-securityexception

I'm working on an app that should be able to broadcast protected intents like `android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW`so that I can see if the necessary system receivers work properly. Currently the app stops and I get a security exception.

Is there anyway to give the app permissions to send these protected broadcasts?

Answer (score 3):

Only system-level processes can broadcast protected intents. An app can't get the persmission to send them in any way, except maybe on a rooted device if you can find a way to start your app as a system process.

Comment: I put my apk in /System/app, and did a reboot. App got installed as System app. But, I am still receiving error when sending broadcast:

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_SET from pid=10176, uid=10118